# Optimizing a one-line find + exec command

Tags: linux, performance, shell, unix, find

I need to get the file information (name, size, date modified) of about 1M+ files on a system. 
The command I am currently using is:

```
sudo find "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING" -type f -exec ls -lT {} +
```

Is there a way to improve this? The only requirement is I must get all the files in the above volumes and for each file, pull the name, size, and date_modified.

(Is there a way to do a stat command here instead? Would that speed things up?)

This takes about an hour on a fiber connected machine.

Comment: With the `+` there, that is going to be close to optimal.  There's an outside chance you can configure `xargs` to run more files at a time than `find` will run (for fewer overall invocations of `ls`), but that's likely to be a second-order effect.

Comment: I have heard that using `xargs` in a pipeline is more efficient that using the `-exec` switch in `find`.

Comment: @David: That's definitely true of `-exec ... ';'` (which runs the command separately for each file), but I doubt `xargs` is much of an improvement over `-exec ... '+'` (which runs many files at a time). The latter is nonstandard, but the OP is already using it, so apparently it's available on his system. And unlike the `xargs` approach, it won't break on filenames that contain whitespace.

Comment: @ruakh You lost me - which is non-standard?  BTW - as I'm sure you're aware, there's a well-known solution for the whitespace issue.

Comment: @David: `-exec ... +` (many-files-per-`-exec`) is nonstandard. And you're right that there's a solution to the whitespace issue, but that solution is also nonstandard, and I don't think it's much more widely supported than `-exec ... +`. So it doesn't have much to recommend it IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of farming the printing out to `ls`, you can use `find`'s built-in printing:

```
sudo find ... -type f -printf '%p      %s      %t\n'
```

I'm not sure how much faster that'll be, but it saves the forking out to `ls`, and it saves having to consult the disk a second time to retrieve information via `ls` that `find` already has anyway, so it should be at least *somewhat* faster.

(By the way, you can search `man find` for `-printf` for more information on those format strings. In particular, you can customize the presentation of the last-modified-time, and you can specify explicit field-widths for the other fields.)